# Python function parameter keep expanding

Tags: python, function, variables

First and foremost, I am a newbie on python. I have a (possibly) trivial question. I have this following code

```
def foo(a=[]):
   a.append(1)
   print a

foo()
foo()
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

I am wondering why the input parameter keeps expanding. I imagine that once we are done calling the function the first time, the variable a in the foo function is out of scope and is thus thrown to garbage. But instead, I see that this variable persists and keeps expanding every time I call foo().

Can anybody please shed some light on how the variables are managed in this case?